# Select Multiple MS Word Pages and Copy the Selection

Tags: vba, ms-word

I would like to select multiple MS word pages and copy all contents and paste it into Excel.
Here is my code so far:

```
   Sub importData()
   Dim wrdDoc As String, i As Long, wordapp As Object

   Set wordapp = CreateObject("word.Application")
   wordapp.Documents.Open "Doc Address"
   wordapp.Visible = True
```

All help greatly appreciated!

Comment: I found this code to be useful:  Dim msword As Word.Application, myWordDoc As Word.Document
    Dim i As Integer
    Set msword = New Word.Application
    
    myFile = "filename"
    
    Set myWordDoc = msword.Documents.Open(myFile)
    msword.Visible = True
    msword.Activate
    myWordDoc.Content.Copy
    ' try to find a way to copy from word and paste into excel
    
    Sheet1.Range("A1").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    
    myWordDoc.Close False
    msword.Quit False
End Sub

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sub wordappstuff()

```
'   declare word app
Dim msword As Word.Application, myWordDoc As Word.Document
Dim i As Integer, sheetName As String, Timer As Double
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
Timer = Now()
Set msword = New Word.Application

For i = 1 To 7
    myFile = "FILENAMEx"
    sheetName = Range("SheetName").Offset(i, 0).Value
    Sheets.Add.Name = sheetName
    Set myWordDoc = msword.Documents.Open(myFile)
  myWordDoc.Content.Copy
Sheets(sheetName).Range("A1").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
myWordDoc.Close False
Next i
msword.Quit False
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
MsgBox (Format(Now() - Timer, "HH:MM:SS"))
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
Sub Demo()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim wdApp As New Word.Application, wdDoc As Word.Document
Const myFile As String = "file path & name"
With wdApp
  Set wdDoc = .Documents.Open(Filename:=myFile, AddToRecentFiles:=False, Visible:=False)
  With wdDoc
    .Range.Copy
    ActiveSheet.Range("A1").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll
    .Close False
  End With
  .Quit False
End With
Set wdDoc = Nothing: Set wdApp = Nothing
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```